# Call subroutine

Tags: excel, call

I am trying to send an email if a condition is met, and it is not working.

If cell D26 on the "Input" tab = "SEND TO OFFICE TO CREATE A BACKORDER", I want to call email, then save the record. The record saving works, but it is not emailing. Thank you in advance!

```
If CS.Range("D26").Value = "DO NOT CREATE A SPECIAL BATCH AND DO NOT BACKORDER." & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "NO CREE UN LOTE ESPECIAL Y NO REALICE PEDIDOS PENDIENTES" Then
    MsgBox ("DO NOT CREATE A SPECIAL BATCH AND DO NOT BACKORDER. NOTHING IS REQUIRED OF YOU FOR THIS ITEM." & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "NO CREE UN LOTE ESPECIAL Y NO REALICE PEDIDOS PENDIENTES. NO SE REQUIERE NADA DE USTED PARA ESTE ARTÍCULO")

End If

If CS.Range("D26").Value = "SEND TO OFFICE TO CREATE A BACKORDER." & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "ENVIAR A OFICINA PARA CREAR UN PEDIDO PENDIENTE" Then

Call Email

lr = PS.Range("A" & PS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

End If

lr = PS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

ArSourceAddress = Array("M4", "G4", "D17", "G14", "G7", "M7", "P7", "G11", "D26", "M14", "G20")

For I = 0 To UBound(ArSourceAddress)
    PS.Cells(lr, I + 1).Value = CS.Range(ArSourceAddress(I)).Value

Next

PS.Cells(lr, 12).Resize(, 4).Value = CS.Range("S24").Resize(, 4).Value

PS.Cells(lr, 16).Resize(, 2).Value = CS.Range("X24").Resize(, 2).Value

MsgBox "THE RECORD HAS BEEN SAVED." & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "EL REGISTRO SE HA GUARDADO."

End Sub

Sub Email ()
Dim oApp As Object
Dim oMail As Object
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutlookMail
.To = "dmrubin25@gmail.com"
.CC = "dmrubin25@gmail.com"
.BCC = "dmrubin25@gmail.com"
  .Subject = "ACTION REQUIRED: ENTER A BACKORDER" & CS.Range("G4").Value & "PO Number " & CS.Range("G20")
 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = "Please create a backorder for the following:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Customer: " & CS.Range("G4").Value & vbNewLine & _
"Customer #: " & CS.Range("M4").Value & vbNewLine & "Quantity: " & CS.Range("R8").Value & vbNewLine & "PO Number: " & CS.Range("G20").Value & _
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Contact for Questions: " & CS.Range("M14").Value
.send
End With
```

Comment: That means that `CS.Range("D26").Value ="SEND TO OFFICE TO CREATE A BACKORDER." & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "ENVIAR A OFICINA PARA CREAR UN PEDIDO PENDIENTE"` is false then.

Comment: @BigBen please explain

Comment: You have an `If` statement. Its result is `False`, so nothing inside the `If...End If` block is executed. In other words, `CS.Range("D26").Value` probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @BigBen That part is working as needed. The part I don't understand is the If CS.Range("D26").Value = "SEND TO OFFICE TO CREATE A BACKORDER." & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "ENVIAR A OFICINA PARA CREAR UN PEDIDO PENDIENTE" Then portion. Why is it not calling the Sub Email subroutine?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You say "it is not emailing." What does that mean specifically? An error occurs, or absolutely nothing happens?

Comment: @BigBen It saves the record but the email is not executed

Comment: Then my initial comment stands. Your second `If` statement is `False`.

Comment: @BigBen please help. I'm not understanding how it is false. I read it as "If D26 = send to office to create a backorder, then call the email subroutine". What am I missing and how do I fix it? I'm an amateur....

Comment: Somehow, what is in cell `D26` is different than `"SEND TO OFFICE TO CREATE A BACKORDER." & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "ENVIAR A OFICINA PARA CREAR UN PEDIDO PENDIENTE"`. It may be spaces, a typo, mabye the `vbCrLf`, but something is different. My suggestion would be try to a smaller portion of that phrase, get that working, and then build up the rest.

Comment: Ah, I see. Good catch. Fixed, but still not working. It saves but doesnt execute the subroutine.